# Python graceful fail on int() call?

Tags: python, fsm

I have to make a rudimentary FSM in a class, and am writing it in Python.  The assignment requires we read the transitions for the machine from a text file.  So for example, a FSM with 3 states, each of which have 2 possible transitions, with possible inputs 'a' and 'b', wolud have a text file that looks like this:

```
2          # first line lists all final states
0 a 1
0 b 2
1 a 0
1 b 2
2 a 0
2 b 1
```

I am trying to come up with a more pythonic way to read a line at a time and convert the states to ints, while keeping the input vals as strings.  Basically this is the idea:

```
self.finalStates = f.readline().strip("\n").split(" ")
for line in f:
  current_state, input_val, next_state = [int(x) for x in line.strip("\n").split(" ")]
```

Of course, when it tries to int("a") it throws a ValueError.  I know I could use a traditional loop and just catch the ValueError but I was hoping to have a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: "Pythonnic way" what do you mean? Writing big hardly reading lines of code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should really only be trying to parse the tokens that you expect to be integers

```
for line in f:
    tokens = line.split(" ")
    current_state, input_val, next_state = int(tokens[0]), tokens[1], int(tokens[2])
```

Arguably more-readable:

```
for line in f:
    current_state, input_val, next_state = parseline(line)

def parseline(line):
    tokens = line.split(" ")
    return (int(tokens[0]), tokens[1], int(tokens[2]))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is something very functional, but I'm not sure if it's "pythonic"... And it may cause some people to scratch their heads. You should really have a "lazy" zip() to do it this way if you have a large number of values:

```
types = [int, str, int]
for line in f:
   current_state, input_val, next_state = multi_type(types, line)

def multi_type(ts,xs): return [t(x) for (t,x) in zip(ts, xs.strip().split())]
```

Also the arguments you use for strip and split can be omitted, because the defaults will work here.

Edit: reformatted - I wouldn't use it as one long line in real code.

Comment: I don't think I'd take this approach if my lines contained only three values, but if they contained more?  Definitely.

Comment: This is also a pretty nice solution if you need to change the "type" function for individual parameters often - i.e. switch parameter 1 from int() to str()

Answer (score 1):

You got excellent answers that match your problem well.  However, in other cases, there may indeed be situations where you want to convert some fields to `int` if feasible (i.e. if they're all digits) and leave them as `str` otherwise (as the title of your question suggests) *without* knowing in advance which fields are ints and which ones are not.

The traditional Python approach is try/except...:

```
def maybeint(s):
  try: return int(s)
  except ValueError: return s
```

...which you need to wrap into a function as there's no way to do a try/except in an expression (e.g. in a list comprehension).  So, you'd use it like:

```
several_fields = [maybeint(x) for x in line.split()]
```

However, it *is* possible to do this specific task inline, if you prefer:

```
several_fields = [(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x) for x in line.split()]
```

the `if`/`else` "ternary operator" looks a bit strange, but one can get used to it;-); and the `isdigit` method of a string gives True if the string is nonempty and only has digits.

To repeat, this is *not* what you should do in your specific case, where you know the specific `int`-`str`-`int` pattern of input types; but it might be appropriate in a more general situation where you don't have such precise information in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.finalStates = [int(state) for state in f.readline().split()]

for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    current_state, input_val, next_state = int(words[0]), words[1], int(words[2])
    # now do something with values
```

Note that you can shorten `line.strip("\n").split(" ")` down to just `line.split()`.  The default behavior of `str.split()` is to split on any white space, and it will return a set of words that have no leading or trailing white space of any sort.

If you are converting the states to `int` in the loop, I presume you want the `finalStates` to be `int` as well.